# in C program if statement is ignored while runtime

Tags: c++, linked-list

While debugging I found in "else if" part the `if(temp->parent==temp1)` statement is not checking `true` or `false`. Control directly jumps to the `Send()` function. Please let me know where it is going wrong.

```
else if(I_Send(my_rank,global_parent,&dest,num_procs))
{

            if(temp->parent==temp1)
            {
                    fix_node[my_rank]==temp;
            }

            Send(fix_node[my_rank],L,sz_vec[fix_node[my_rank]->node_num],fix_node[my_rank],dest,temp1);

            temp1=temp1->parent;
            if(temp1!=NULL)
            local_parent=temp1->node_num;
    }
```

Comment: How did you know it's not checked?

Comment: Put an else after that if statement and print something.

Comment: If it's just skipping over the block, it's probably evaluating out to false. We need more code to actually tell, though.

Comment: At the start of the function print the value of templ->parent, print the value of temp1, then within the if() statement, print a message like "Evalued to True", and make an else{ printf("Evaluated to False\n"); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside the `if` body has no effect...

```
fix_node[my_rank]==temp;
```

I think you meant to do an assignment (**=**) instead of comparison (**==**)